# popViewControllerAnimated: custom transition animation?

Tags: xcode, animation, uinavigationcontroller, transition

Yes, I have looked for an answer already. None of the solutions work, except one that doesn't give the option for a fade transition, only flip or curl.

Like this:

```
methodname
    configure animation
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
```

No matter what variety of transition animation config I try, nothing is visibly different from only using the typical single-line pop. If I change it to `…Animated:YES];`, I get the standard pop animation, maybe with something weird happening from the broken config.

So my question is this: How can I do a `pop` with, if not `CrossDissolve`, then at least something that looks the same? Is that even possible with a navigation controller?

Using modal views would have the default animation I want, and I could manage the view stack easily enough, but I don't want to do that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

For this type of transition I would really recommend a modal view controller, thats the way the system was designed.

But if you insist on using the navigation controller there is a way, though somewhat ugly.

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];

CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
[transition setType:kCATransitionFade];
[self.navigationController.view.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"someAnimation"];

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
[CATransaction commit];
```

The `CATransaction` will disable all standard animations. The `CATransition` adds a fade transition to the navigation controller layer when views are swapped (in this case removing the viewcontroller view that is popped).

Comment: In iOS 7 I'm finding that I need to pass NO to popViewControllerAnimated rather than YES, but otherwise this works nicely.

Answer (score 2):

In iOS 7 above, you may want to look into `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` for presented view controllers, or `UINavigationControllerDelegate` method :

```
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC
```

I have some [sample code from another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22884111/how-to-use-uiviewcontrolleranimatedtransitioning-with-uinavigationcontroller/25026102#25026102) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Joris Kluivers's answer in Swift 3 :

```
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

let animation = CATransition()
animation.type = kCATransitionFade
self.navigationController?.view.layer.add(animation, forKey: "someAnimation")
_ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)

CATransaction.commit()
```