# iOS 6.1 No animation when pop view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

When pop a view, I am using the below code:

```
[UIView  beginAnimations: @"Showinfo" context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationCurve: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];

[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromLeft forView:self.navigationController.view cache:NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This code gives a flip effect when pop a view, which works for iOS 7.0 and above. When it is in 6.1, it only shows the normal sliding animation without any flip effect. I am not sure which part 6.1 doesn't like, and what could be a possible fix.

P.S. I am using similar code for `pushViewControllerAnimated` and it can show the flip, it just can't work with pop.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10553264/popviewcontrolleranimated-custom-transition-animation